# In Vue.js, how to set a piece of data to always equal the containing element's height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to bind a piece of data to always equal the containing element's height. The height changes due to other user interactions (i.e. window resize).

Within a computed property, when I try to access the `this.$el` field, the element hasn't been properly set up yet.

So I'm wondering if there's any way to gracefully set a piece of data to always equals a dom element's height.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a way to track the element's height changes then you can do the following (using Vue.js and jQuery of course):

**HTML**

```
...
<body>
    ...
    <div v-el='target_element'></div>
    ...
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: 'body',
        data: {
            height: 0
        },
        ready: function () {
            var self = this;
            self.height = $(self.$$.target_element).height();

            // Here you listen for change in the target div's height
            // For Example ...
            $(window).on('resize', function() {
                self.height = $(self.$$.target_element).height();
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Hopefully this will help ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My data is a tree (similar to the Vue.js Tree View example). So, the elements I need to track are nested. Using jQuery on a global level may not be ideal. Also, it's not just the `resize` event that I need to track. Ideally, I want to track the height every time it changes (most of the time, it's Vue.js that alters element's heights). I feel like my problem can be solved if we can access the finished dom element ($el) within computed properties.

Comment: @Dave I think the computed properties are calculated before the DOM is finished loading and that's probably why you are getting _element hasn't been properly set up yet._, try including Vue.js in the `<head>` section. Been using Vue.js for only about a month so please excuse my uncertainty ;)

Comment: In Vue v2, `ready` has changed to `mounted`: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced

Answer (score 0):

I created an directive that binds a specified components data variable to the height (in my case, the width) of the element the directive is applied to.

The directive I define in observe-height.js:

```
export default {
name:'observeHeight',

inserted:function(el, binding, vnode) {
  if(binding.arg && vnode.context.hasOwnProperty(binding.arg)) {
    function emitHeightValue(event) {
      vnode.context[binding.arg] = el.offsetHeight;
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', emitHeightValue);
    emitWidthValue();
  }
 }
};
```

And then apply the directive to the html element within the component's template who's dimensions you want to observe:

```
    <template>
      <div v-observe-height:myHeightVar></div>
    </tempate>
    <script>
    import observeWidth from 'observe-width';
    Vue.directive(observeHeight.name, observeHeight);

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          myHeightVar: 0
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```